# Why is my KendoUI Grid showing duplicate records in my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I am using a KendoUI grid in my ASP.NET Core application, when I return data to my grid it shows the same record twice.  The grid gets its data from my repository and the annotated entity looks for a view called `ViewVesselCrane`.  It should return rows of data that match a specific ID called `VesselId` but what it seems to do is return the correct number of results but they are all the same data.

To start, here is my my view:

**ViewVesselCrane.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyCompany.Data.Views
{
    [Table("ViewVesselCrane")]
    public class ViewVesselCrane
    {
        [Key]

        public int DeckEquipmentId { get; set; }
        public int? VesselId { get; set; }
        public int? CraneTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfCranes { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public int? SWL { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Services/CraneViewService.cs**

```
using MyCompany.Data.Views;
using MyCompany.Repo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyCompany.Services.Views
{
    public class CraneViewService : ICraneViewService
    {
        private IRepository<ViewVesselCrane> viewCraneRepository;

        public CraneViewService(IRepository<ViewVesselCrane> viewCraneRepository)
        {
            this.viewCraneRepository = viewCraneRepository;
        }
        public IEnumerable<ViewVesselCrane> GetCranes()
        {
            return viewCraneRepository.GetAll();
        }
        public ViewVesselCrane GetCrane(int id)
        {
            return viewCraneRepository.Get(id);
        }
        public void InsertCrane(ViewVesselCrane crane)
        {
            viewCraneRepository.Insert(crane);
        }
        public void UpdateCrane(ViewVesselCrane crane)
        {
            viewCraneRepository.Update(crane);
        }
        public void DeleteCrane(int id)
        {
            ViewVesselCrane crane = GetCrane(id);
            viewCraneRepository.Remove(crane);
            viewCraneRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Services/ICraneViewService.cs**

```
using MyCompany.Data.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyCompany.Services.Views
{
    public interface ICraneViewService
    {
        IEnumerable<ViewVesselCrane> GetCranes();
        ViewVesselCrane GetCrane(int id);
        void InsertCrane(ViewVesselCrane crane);
        void UpdateCrane(ViewVesselCrane crane);
        void DeleteCrane(int id);
    }
}
```

The code for the grid, which is using TagHelper is:

**Grid**

```
<kendo-grid name="cranesGrid" height="250">
        <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80">
            <transport>                    
                <read url="@Url.Action("CraneRead", "Vessel")" />
            </transport>

        </datasource>

        <columns>
            <column field="DeckEquipmentId" title="Deck Equip. Id" />
            <column field="VesselId" title="VesselId" />
            <column field="TypeName" title="TypeName" />
            <column field="NumberOfCranes" title="No. Cranes" />
            <column field="CraneId" title="CraneId" />                

        </columns>
    </kendo-grid>
```

**Controllers/VesselController/GetCranes**

Please note, I have hardcoded an Id just for testing purposes, in production the Id is passed to the controller as an optional parameter via javascript function bound to the grid's `data` option in transport.

```
 public ActionResult CraneRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? id)
    {
        var data = _craneService.GetCranes().Where(x => x.VesselId == 21059);
        var result = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Ok, so that's the basic setup.  Now for the view,  it's quite basic, joining three tables together.  If I run the view and pass in a `VesselId` using SSMS I see the results as expected.  If I run the application I see the correct number of results but the data looks the same and it shouldn't.

**ViewVesselCrane**

```
SELECT O.DeckEquipmentId, P.TypeName, I.SWL, I.NumberOfCranes, I.CraneTypeId, O.VesselId
FROM dbo.DeckEquipment AS O LEFT JOIN
                         dbo.Crane AS I ON O.DeckEquipmentId = I.DeckEquipmentId LEFT JOIN
                         dbo.CraneType AS P ON P.CraneTypeId = I.CraneTypeId
```

I'm not sure where this problem is stemming from, given that the SQL query works when I test it, I can only assume I have done something incorrectly in my application and I need a little help to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little more digging into this, I found that the problem came down to the view itself, EF tried to understand a unique key which I had defined using the '[Key]' annotation in the entity but it wasn't actually unique, for that reason duplicates were turned.  I added an additional column (that I don't use) which is unique and applied the key annotation to that and it now works.

Comment: Your own answer just saved me a bunch of additional troubleshooting!!